# Replace keys in a tuple in Erlang

Tags: erlang, tuples

I have a list of tuples eg. [{1,40},{2,45},{3,54}....{7,23}] where 1...7 are days of the week (calculated by finding calendar:day_of_the_week()). So now I want to change the list to [{Mon,40},{Tue,45},{Wed,54}...{Sun,23}]. Is there an easier way to do it than lists:keyreplace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple. Use map and a handy tool from the httpd module.

```
lists:map(fun({A,B}) -> {httpd_util:day(A),B} end, [{1,40},{2,45},{3,54},{7,23}]).
```

Answer (score 13):

... or using a different syntax:

```
[{httpd_util:day(A), B} || {A,B} <- L]
```

where:

```
L = [{1,40},{2,45},{3,54}....{7,23}]
```

The construct is called a *[list comprehension](http://www.erlang.org/doc/programming_examples/list_comprehensions.html#3)*, and reads as:

> "Build a list of `{httpd_util:day(A),B}` tuples, where `{A,B}` is taken from the list `L`"